# Returning 0 or 1 for a SQL duplicate query

Tags: sql, teradata

Working with Teradata if that matters...

What I have is a duplicate check that looks like this:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
FROM TBL_A
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
GROUP BY ID;
```

If there are no duplicates it returns 0 rows, if there are duplicates it shows what they are.  That's fine, but what I want is the return to either be 0 (if no duplicates) or 1 if duplicates are found.  That's it.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: do you need such info for each id?

Comment: @vkp this is another query needed for automated testing purposes.  I still have the initial query that runs to show the duplicates themselves, but I needed a way to assign 0's and 1's for this specific purpose.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is a `case`:

```
select (case when count(id) = count(distinct id) then 0 else 1 end)
from tbl_a;
```

Note:  This ignores id when it has a `NULL` value.  If you need to take that into account, it is easy to modify the query.

Comment: that works thank you.  This will be used on natural key columns so no NULLs will be present.   I am assuming if there is more than one field in they Key I just append those fields to both count() sections like I would normally.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a multi-column key you can't use Gordon's apporach as aggregate functions only work on a single column.

A possible workaround would be combining those columns into one like this

```
COUNT(column1 || column2 || column3)
```

but it's probably not very efficient.

Otherwise you need to add another COUNT using a Derived Table:

```
select case when count(*) = 0 then 0 else 1 end
from
 (
   SELECT column1, column2, column3, COUNT(*)
   FROM TBL_A
   GROUP BY 1,2,3
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) as dt
```

You should compare resource usage, should be similar to `COUNT(DISTINCT ID)` for single column, but less CPU for multi-column.